# How to send an API frame to a remote XBee using Digi XBee Python module?

Tags: python, beagleboneblack, xbee

I am moving code from Python XBee library to Digi's Python XBee library and I am unable to locate syntax in the docs on how to send a API frame to a remote XBee.  I am using S1 and S1 Pro devices where the "local" device is attached to a Beaglebone and the "remote" devices are standalone out in the wild.

I have the basic framework down:

```
from digi.xbee.devices import XBeeDevice, RemoteXBeeDevice, XBee64BitAddress

PORT = '/dev/ttyO1'
BAUD = 9600
API_FRAME = 'long-hex-string-here'

local_xbee = XBeeDevice(PORT, BAUD)
local_xbee.open()

# Instantiate a remote XBee device object.
remote_xbee = RemoteXBeeDevice(local_xbee, XBee64BitAddress.from_hex_string("0013A20040DD7DCD"))

# Transmit frame to remote_xbee - unsure of correct method and syntax
# perhaps XBeePacket.create_packet(hex string here)
# local_xbee.send_data(remote_xbee, "api frame here?")  ??

local_xbee.close()
```

but I am unable to locate syntax for how to transmit my constructed API frame.  Based upon the Introduction section in the docs I presume that is the correct approach.  I am not interested in broadcasting to all devices on the network but rather unicast communication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have some older model of the source when I could get it to work.

…

I have some WiFi Xbee modules that I used w/ some converter boards (base boards). I used it to attach the communication of the Xbee from one computer to another, e.g. random desktop to BeagleBone Black via USB instead of UART. So, I would use the source, listed below, to attach my USB dongle for the Xbee communication from the BBB to the other field module.

Their I/O stuff can be found here: https://github.com/digidotcom/xbee-python/tree/master/examples/io.

Also...changing just some of their lines in their source w/ the USB dongle WiFi adapter boards proved valuable in signaling LEDs and other sensors.

Oh and you will need what they are now calling Carrier Boards. It is the adapter board I just typed out. So, if you have already got a Carrier Board, use lsusb as the command in Linux to find your USB "name."

So, for instance, if lsusb brings up `/dev/ttyUSB0`, then that is the port identification.

And you can use that section, from lsusb, to then change your xbee modules in the xtcu software from Digi.

…

```
from digi.xbee.devices import XBeeDevice
from digi.xbee.io import IOLine, IOMode
import time
import threading

# TODO: Replace with the serial port where your local module is connected to.
PORT = "/dev/ttyUSB0"
# TODO: Replace with the baud rate of your local module.
BAUD_RATE = 9600

REMOTE_NODE_ID = "Xbee_B"

IOLINE_IN = IOLine.DIO2_AD2
IOLINE_OUT = IOLine.DIO4_AD4

def main():
    print(" +-----------------------------------------------+")
    print(" | XBee Python Library Get/Set Remote DIO Sample |")
    print(" +-----------------------------------------------+\n")

    stop = False
    th = None

    local_device = XBeeDevice(PORT, BAUD_RATE)

    try:
        local_device.open()
        print("local device: ", local_device.get_node_id())
        # Obtain the remote XBee device from the XBee network.
        xbee_network = local_device.get_network()
        remote_device = xbee_network.discover_device(REMOTE_NODE_ID)
        if local_device is None:
            print("Could not find the remote device")
            exit(2)

        def io_detection_callback():
            while not stop:
                # Read the digital value from the input line.
                io_value = remote_device.get_dio_value(IOLINE_IN)
                print("%s: %s" % (IOLINE_IN, io_value))

                # Set the previous value to the local output line.
                local_device.set_dio_value(IOLINE_OUT, io_value)

                time.sleep(2)

        th = threading.Thread(target=io_detection_callback)

        remote_device.set_io_configuration(IOLINE_IN, IOMode.DIGITAL_IN)

        local_device.set_io_configuration(IOLINE_OUT, IOMode.DIGITAL_OUT_HIGH)

        time.sleep(1)
        th.start()

        input()

    finally:
        stop = True
        if th is not None and th.is_alive():
            th.join()
        if local_device is not None and local_device.is_open():
            local_device.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

So, see the PORT = "/dev/ttyUSB0" section of the source?

This is where I attached my Xbee module to the Carrier Board and then attached the Carrier Board to the BBB by way of USB.

Um, this may not answer a question but give more insight as to how to handle Digi Devices/Modules.

I also think that if you want to venture in this direction of UART communication w/ Xbee and the BeagleBone Black, it may be more complicated. I will keep searching my text.

P.S. This book goes over some methods to connect, Experiment 10 and Experiment 16, your "BBB" to a UART, Xbee, and how to communicate. It is a bit too in depth to get all of the communication ideas from this book but this is it:

```
The Hands-on XBEE Lab Manual, Experiments that Teach you XBEE Wireless Communications – Jonathan A Titus
```

Comment: Thank you for posting this very helpful answer.  It doesn't answer my direct question but may actually prove more helpful in the long run.  I have the Titus book you mention and have corresponded with the author.  I didn't realize it contained any code which used the Digi libraries.  I will definitely check that out.  Also, I will post here if I figure out how to send full API frames.  Again, thank you!

Comment: Using the set_io_configuration() method I am now able to set digital IO levels on my remote XBees.  Thank you again.

Comment: Nice...the book has info. on how to promote UART based communication in the specified chapters, 10 and 16.

Comment: A note from the Digi project which may help others going down this path:  _"When you communicate with an XBee (your local device or any remote), the library is already sending API frames. API frames are used for any operation with your XBee devices: local and remote configuration, data transmission/reception to/from a remote, network discovery, getting IO samples, etc."_